# Type error while trying to concat two dataframes in python

Tags: python, types, concatenation

I'm trying to concat two dataframes in python 3 with the following code :

```
a=group.sort_values('datetime',ascending=True)
r=np.arange(1,a.shape[0]+1)
points = pandas.DataFrame(r,columns=['points'])
a = pandas.concat([a,points],axis=1)
```

a is a dataframe with datetimes, strings and boolean

This results to this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/wymeka/Documents/ENSAE/DataViz_twitter/org/ensae/dataviz/scraping/utils/json_parsing.py", line 123, in <module>
print(fastest_tweet_qag())
File "C:/Users/wymeka/Documents/ENSAE/DataViz_twitter/org/ensae/dataviz/scraping/utils/json_parsing.py", line 110, in fastest_tweet_qag
groups.apply(fastest)
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 713, in apply
return self._python_apply_general(f)
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 717, in _python_apply_general
self.axis)
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1347, in apply
res = f(group)
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 709, in f
return func(g, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:/Users/wymeka/Documents/ENSAE/DataViz_twitter/org/ensae/dataviz/scraping/utils/json_parsing.py", line 92, in fastest
group=pandas.concat([group,points],axis=1)
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 810, in concat
return op.get_result()
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 992, in get_result
mgrs_indexers, self.new_axes, concat_axis=self.axis, copy=self.copy)
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4277, in concatenate_block_managers
for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4277, in <listcomp>
for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
 File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4370, in concatenate_join_units
empty_dtype, upcasted_na = get_empty_dtype_and_na(join_units)
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4305, in get_empty_dtype_and_na
dtypes[i] = unit.dtype
File "pandas\src\properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.__get__ (pandas\lib.c:43950)
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4584, in dtype
self.block.fill_value)[0])
File "C:\Users\wymeka\Documents\Python\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 1103, in _maybe_promote
elif issubclass(np.dtype(dtype).type, compat.string_types):
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Well if python doesn't understand the data type, i do not what I need to do?

Help please.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post the full error message including traceback.